# How to remove the Setup Wizard app in Android 4+?

Tags: android, adb

I need to bypass the setup wizard on my Nexus 5 running 4.4 only using ADB as my digitizer and screen are broken. I just want to find the Setup Wizard app and remove it via ADB. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wizard is inside the "GoogleServiceFramework.apk", in the system/app folder. You need to root and remount your system to rw to delete the apk. But after you delete it, you cannot use any Goolge service.

However, the mechanism behind this setup wizard is simple. It just declares that it is also a "HOME" application with priority=2. So you can just use package manager (pm) on adb shell to disable the wizard start up activity. Then you can see the normal home application directly.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. However I found the SetupWizard.apk in /system/priv-app or something along those lines. I just backed it up and renamed it.

Comment: deleted that file but the setup wizard is still present, any clue?

Comment: When you see the wizard activity on top, use "dumpsys activity" to see its package/class name, and use "pm path com.wizard.name" to find the apk.